# kubectl stops working after reboot

Tags: kubernetes

I've installed Kubernetes 1.9.2 on the master node (Ubuntu 16.04) including the dashboard.

All the pods were running fine. **After rebooting**, when I try to run `kubectl get nodes` I get the following:

```
The connection to the server 10.50.88.230:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

If I run `kubectl cluster-info` I get:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.50.88.230:6443

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server 10.50.88.230:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

If I run `kubectl cluster-info dump` I get the same error. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: is the kubelet running?

Comment: How can I check that? If I run kubelet I get:
I0129 14:57:27.283287   61765 feature_gate.go:220] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
I0129 14:57:27.283401   61765 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
I0129 14:57:27.283411   61765 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flags
error: error reading /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key, certificate and key must be supplied as a pair

Comment: Are you using minikube?

Comment: _How can I check that?_ `ps -efw | grep kubelet`, and if still using `init.d` then `/etc/init.d/kubelet status` (or such), if `systemd` then `systemctl status kubelet.service`

Comment: its' not minikube, it's regular kubernetes.

Comment: `ps -efw | grep kubelet` shows there is a kubelet process.

Comment: `systemctl status kubelet.service` shows: 
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-01-30 03:37:47 PST; 5s ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
  Process: 45933 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS $KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS $KUBELET_DNS_ARGS $KUB
 Main PID: 45933 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: How did you init the master? If you had proxy settings, you may try to restore them, something like:

`NO_PROXY=localhost,localhost.,10.50.88.230, 10.50.88.231... ;  export NO_PROXY`

Comment: It's a new EC2 instance. It should not have any proxy settings. I have initialized the master like this:
`sudo swapoff -a ;
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 ;
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube ;
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config ;
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config ;
sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1 ;
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

Comment: Might be an expired token, you can `kubeadm token create` a new one.

Comment: I'm not trying to join a new node. Anyway I've tried that and I got `unable to create bootstrap token after 5 attempts [<nil>]`. If I do `kubeadm token list` I get `failed to list bootstrap tokens [Get https://10.50.88.230:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/secrets?fieldSelector=type%3Dbootstrap.kubernetes.io%2Ftoken: dial tcp 10.50.88.230:6443: getsockopt: connection refused]`

Comment: If I do a `kubeadm reset` and then again all the initialisation above again, it works. But if I reboot I have the same problem again. Is there anything to do with authorization certificates? Also when I run the Kubernetes dashboard I'm asked to sign in and provide a kubeconfig or a token. I don't understand how to do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it turns out that it's normal that Kubernetes stops working after a reboot.
Need to write a script that runs at boot time and that automates the installation steps, like `kubeadm reset` and all the following initialisation steps.

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: sudo swapoff -a

Answer (score 4):

The issue may arise due to following reasons:

1. Kubernetes does not work with "Swap" in place.

   Temporary solution:

> ```
> sudo -i
> swapoff -a
> exit
> strace -eopenat kubectl version
> ```

```
Permanent solution:
```

> ```
> Remove any reference to "swap" from file /etc/fstab
> ```

2. When the system is rebooted,IP changes and hence the previously initialised 
   network is not being served on the same address anymore. You might see the 
   following error when you run any kubectl command:
   Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp XXX.XXX.X.XXX:6443: i/o timeout

   Temporary solution:

> Reinitialise the network(assuming user is not working with minikube): 
>     sudo kubeadm reset 
>     sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.16/24

```
Permanent solution:
```

> Make your system's IP static.

Comment: sudo swapoff -a

Answer (score 0):

"kubectl get ns/no" commands will work if, LoadBalancer IP/hostname entry had in "/etc/hosts" and it will work all times (even after reboot). If you do "kubeadm reset", complete data in the cluster will be lost.

Thanks,
Sudheerr

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).